# Папки в Pop!_Os Gnome не сохраняют месторасположение на рабочем столе

Tags: linux

Установил себе Pop!_Os Gnome. Установил парочку программ. Создал пару папок на рабочем столе. После перезагрузки системы папки всегда перемещаются к левому краю. Как поступить, чтобы папки оставались на местах их расположения?

Answer (score 0):

установи nemo и запусти его автостартом, скопировав  /usr/share/applications/nemo-autostart.desktop в ~/.config/autostart/nemo-autostart.desktop

в наутилусе и в шеле надо отключить значки на рабочем столе.